# Livewire - Refresh Multiple Instances of the Same Component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm using Laravel 8.12 with Livewire 2.6.
I have a page that displays all the addresses for a customer.
Each address 'card' is an instance of the **same** Livewire component.
Cards are colour coded to show which address is the default address (green = default).
Each card has an 'edit' button that allows the address to be edited and set as the default address for the customer.

When an address is set as default, all the other addresses are marked as not-default. If the address being edited is set as default, when the save button is clicked it updates an the background turns green to show it is the default. However, no other address components refresh at this point - so the previously default address is still displayed in green until the whole page is reloaded.

I'd like **ALL** the address components on the page to refresh when any single instance is saved.

I've tried using the refresh method like this:

On my `CustomerAddress.php` component:

```
    protected $listeners = [
        '$refresh',
    ];
```

and

```
    public function submitForm()
    {
        $this->validate();
        $this->save();
        $this->editable = false;

        //Refresh the address data to update the display.
        $this->address->refresh();
        $this->emitTo('livewire.customers.customer-address', '$refresh');
    }
```

but this has not worked. Only the instance being edited refreshes.

Any suggestions? Is this even possible? Or do I need to force a whole page reload with a redirect?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should refresh your parent component's data, like the customerAddress collection, once this parent component should rerender the updated collection and hydrate all the properties, update the nested components and the DOM elements

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Prospero . The issue is that the parent data (Customer) is fed into the view via route model binding from the controller. So each LiveWire instance of CustomerAddress does not have an awareness of Customer - so I can't see how a single instnace could refresh the parent data and force all the other instances to refresh. Maybe a page reload is the way to go?

Comment: you should convert the parent to livewire component instead

Comment: Thanks again @Prospero - I don’t want to convert the whole page into a Livewire component - but I might cover the div that holds the addresses - that would likely solve the issue as I could emit a refresh call to that component. Thanks again for the suggestion - sounds like that’s the way to go.